# open xml tables in excel

Tags: excel, xml, powerquery

I am trying to open an xml file to excel using power query. But, the issue is it keeps on going in loop and created more then 1 million rows and file size grows to 100 gb.

The code I used is
let
Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("C:\Users\anujk\Downloads\stock_export_full_for_anujkundu.xml")),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Attribute:file_format", type text}, {"Attribute:version", type number}, {"Attribute:generated", type datetime}, {"Attribute:extensions", type text}}),
#"Expanded products" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "products", {"product", "Attribute:language", "Attribute:currency"}, {"products.product", "products.Attribute:language", "products.Attribute:currency"}),
#"Expanded products.product" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products", "products.product", {"producer", "category", "http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml", "unit", "series", "card", "description", "price", "srp", "sizes", "images", "parameters", "group", "attachments", "Attribute:id", "Attribute:vat", "Attribute:type", "Attribute:producer_code_standard", "Attribute:code_on_card", "strikethrough_retail_price"}, {"products.product.producer", "products.product.category", "products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml", "products.product.unit", "products.product.series", "products.product.card", "products.product.description", "products.product.price", "products.product.srp", "products.product.sizes", "products.product.images", "products.product.parameters", "products.product.group", "products.product.attachments", "products.product.Attribute:id", "products.product.Attribute:vat", "products.product.Attribute:type", "products.product.Attribute:producer_code_standard", "products.product.Attribute:code_on_card", "products.product.strikethrough_retail_price"}),
#"Expanded products.product.category" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product", "products.product.category", {"Attribute:id", "Attribute:name"}, {"products.product.category.Attribute:id", "products.product.category.Attribute:name"}),
#"Expanded products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.category", "products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml", {"iai_category"}, {"products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml.iai_cat"}),
#"Expanded products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml.iai_cat" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml", "products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml.iai_cat", {"Attribute:id", "Attribute:path"}, {"products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml.iai_c.1", "products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml.iai_c.2"}),
#"Expanded products.product.series" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml.iai_cat", "products.product.series", {"Attribute:id", "Attribute:name"}, {"products.product.series.Attribute:id", "products.product.series.Attribute:name"}),
#"Expanded products.product.card" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.series", "products.product.card", {"Attribute:url"}, {"products.product.card.Attribute:url"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.card", "products.product.description", {"name", "version", "long_desc", "short_desc"}, {"products.product.description.name", "products.product.description.version", "products.product.description.long_desc", "products.product.description.short_desc"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description", "products.product.description.name", {"Element:Text", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}, {"products.product.description.name.Element:Text", "products.product.description.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.name", "products.product.description.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", {"Attribute:lang"}, {"products.product.description.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.Attribute"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.version" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "products.product.description.version", {"Element:Text", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}, {"products.product.description.version.Element:Text", "products.product.description.version.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.version.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.version", "products.product.description.version.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", {"Attribute:lang"}, {"products.product.description.version.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.Attrib"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.long_desc" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.version.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "products.product.description.long_desc", {"Element:Text", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}, {"products.product.description.long_desc.Element:Text", "products.product.description.long_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.long_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.long_desc", "products.product.description.long_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", {"Attribute:lang"}, {"products.product.description.long_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.Attr"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.short_desc" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.long_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "products.product.description.short_desc", {"Element:Text", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}, {"products.product.description.short_desc.Element:Text", "products.product.description.short_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}),
#"Expanded products.product.description.short_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.short_desc", "products.product.description.short_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", {"Attribute:lang"}, {"products.product.description.short_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.Att"}),
#"Expanded products.product.price" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.description.short_desc.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "products.product.price", {"Attribute:gross", "Attribute:net"}, {"products.product.price.Attribute:gross", "products.product.price.Attribute:net"}),
#"Expanded products.product.srp" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.price", "products.product.srp", {"Attribute:gross", "Attribute:net"}, {"products.product.srp.Attribute:gross", "products.product.srp.Attribute:net"}),
#"Expanded products.product.sizes" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.srp", "products.product.sizes", {"size"}, {"products.product.sizes.size"}),
#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.sizes", "products.product.sizes.size", {"stock", "price", "srp", "Attribute:id", "Attribute:text_id", "Attribute:code_producer", "Attribute:code", "Attribute:weight"}, {"products.product.sizes.size.stock", "products.product.sizes.size.price", "products.product.sizes.size.srp", "products.product.sizes.size.Attribute:id", "products.product.sizes.size.Attribute:text_id", "products.product.sizes.size.Attribute:code_producer", "products.product.sizes.size.Attribute:code", "products.product.sizes.size.Attribute:weight"}),
#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.stock" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size", "products.product.sizes.size.stock", {"Attribute:id", "Attribute:quantity", "http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml"}, {"products.product.sizes.size.stock.Attribute:id", "products.product.sizes.size.stock.Attribute:quantity", "products.product.sizes.size.stock.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi"}),
#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.stock.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.stock", "products.product.sizes.size.stock.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi", {"Attribute:location_id", "Attribute:location_text_id"}, {"products.product.sizes.size.stock.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/exten.1", "products.product.sizes.size.stock.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/exten.2"}),
#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.price" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.stock.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi", "products.product.sizes.size.price", {"Attribute:gross", "Attribute:net"}, {"products.product.sizes.size.price.Attribute:gross", "products.product.sizes.size.price.Attribute:net"}),
#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.srp" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.price", "products.product.sizes.size.srp", {"Attribute:gross", "Attribute:net"}, {"products.product.sizes.size.srp.Attribute:gross", "products.product.sizes.size.srp.Attribute:net"}),
#"Expanded products.product.images" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.sizes.size.srp", "products.product.images", {"large", "icons"}, {"products.product.images.large", "products.product.images.icons"}),
#"Expanded products.product.images.large" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.images", "products.product.images.large", {"image"}, {"products.product.images.large.image"}),
#"Expanded products.product.images.large.image" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.images.large", "products.product.images.large.image", {"Attribute:url", "Attribute:date_changed", "Attribute:hash", "Attribute:width", "Attribute:height"}, {"products.product.images.large.image.Attribute:url", "products.product.images.large.image.Attribute:date_changed", "products.product.images.large.image.Attribute:hash", "products.product.images.large.image.Attribute:width", "products.product.images.large.image.Attribute:height"}),
#"Expanded products.product.parameters" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.images.large.image", "products.product.parameters", {"parameter"}, {"products.product.parameters.parameter"}),
#"Expanded products.product.parameters.parameter" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.parameters", "products.product.parameters.parameter", {"value", "Attribute:type", "Attribute:id", "Attribute:priority", "Attribute:name"}, {"products.product.parameters.parameter.value", "products.product.parameters.parameter.Attribute:type", "products.product.parameters.parameter.Attribute:id", "products.product.parameters.parameter.Attribute:priority", "products.product.parameters.parameter.Attribute:name"}),
#"Expanded products.product.parameters.parameter.value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.parameters.parameter", "products.product.parameters.parameter.value", {"Attribute:id", "Attribute:priority", "Attribute:name"}, {"products.product.parameters.parameter.value.Attribute:id", "products.product.parameters.parameter.value.Attribute:priority", "products.product.parameters.parameter.value.Attribute:name"}),
#"Expanded products.product.group" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.parameters.parameter.value", "products.product.group", {"group_by_parameter", "Attribute:id", "Attribute:first_product_id"}, {"products.product.group.group_by_parameter", "products.product.group.Attribute:id", "products.product.group.Attribute:first_product_id"}),
#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.group", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter", {"name", "product_value", "Attribute:id"}, {"products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.product_value", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.Attribute:id"}),
#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name", {"Element:Text", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}, {"products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name.Element:Text", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namesp"}),
#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namesp" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namesp", {"Attribute:lang"}, {"products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/name.1"}),
#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter.product_value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namesp", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.product_value", {"name", "Attribute:id"}, {"products.product.group.group_by_parameter.product_value.name", "products.product.group.group_by_parameter.product_value.Attribute:id"}),
#"Expanded products.product.attachments" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.group.group_by_parameter.product_value", "products.product.attachments", {"file"}, {"products.product.attachments.file"}),
#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.attachments", "products.product.attachments.file", {"name", "Attribute:url", "Attribute:priority", "Attribute:attachment_file_extension", "http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensions.phtml"}, {"products.product.attachments.file.name", "products.product.attachments.file.Attribute:url", "products.product.attachments.file.Attribute:priority", "products.product.attachments.file.Attribute:attachment_file_extension", "products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi"}),
#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file.name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file", "products.product.attachments.file.name", {"Element:Text", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}, {"products.product.attachments.file.name.Element:Text", "products.product.attachments.file.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}),
#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file.name", "products.product.attachments.file.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", {"Attribute:lang"}, {"products.product.attachments.file.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace.Attr"}),
#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file.name.http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi", {"Attribute:enable", "Attribute:attachment_file_type", "Attribute:download_log"}, {"products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/exten.1", "products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/exten.2", "products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/exten.3"})
in
#"Expanded products.product.attachments.file.http://www.iai-shop.com/developers/iof/extensi"

Comment: @ron-rosenfeld Kindly help

Comment: Do you really need all that data? Perhaps you can pre-process it and do some filtering with XPath to begin with for just the data you are interested in.

Comment: I have never used X-path before, and it will be a great help if you can guide me.

Comment: https://devhints.io/xpath - XSLT could be used to reduce number of columns - doing transformations.. XPath would allow you to filter rows (but also pull out certain buckets of information).  You will probably find a lot of examples on Youtube. W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xquery.asp would give you and intro. But then I'd look at the likes of https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:XQuery_processors

Comment: http://www.qutoric.com/xmlquire/ - may help - have never used it personally..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFXwJ0UWVJQ